# Why can I not remove python 2.6 and 2.7 from usr/lib/?

Tags: python, sudo, rm, file-organization

`MacBook-Pro:lib me$ sudo rm -rf python2.6
rm: python2.6: Operation not permitted`

I tried with sudo, without sudo. Not sure why the operation is not permitted.

Comment: Also: simply don't. Other system programs may rely on those Python installations (I assume you meant `/usr/lib/`, with the initial slash).

Comment: Even if system allows the deletion, DO NOT delete python installation. System files may depend on them. Always try to use python in virtual environments for your developments. Its really bad practice to use system wide installation.

Comment: wait so macs use python before you even have it installed? i deleted alot of 2.7 folders, at least the ones i could delete. any tips on a virtual env? im using homebrew- thought that was a virtual env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), introduced by Apple on OSX versions El Capitan and onwards.